# Can I permanently remove a song from not playing on a dvd

Tags: dvd

Recently I bought a DVD with song videos on it. It is a very good song collections DVD. But there are some songs whose videos are not appropirate for children. So how can I filter not to play those particular songs from the DVD. Is there anything that can be done permanently or just temporarily?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is you can not change the existing DVD.  However, for personal use only, you can make a copy omitting the offensive content.  The difficulty of the process depends on how the dvd was made/organized.  There should be a a VIDEO or VIDEO_TS folder on the DVD when viewed from the computer.  You could get lucky and they could be named/numbered so you can identify the offending content.  Do you see a bunch of files with the VOB extension?  If you play these using videolan from videolan.org you should be able to find the offending content.  If you can you can make a copy without said file.  Otherwise it is part of one of the files and you will need to edit the video in a video editor to cut out the offensive content.  When you make a new DVD with the edited file the content will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

DVD's are (usually) a locked format. As such, there is no way to "lock" those tracks, unless you want to damage your DVD.

Fun aside, what you can do is to try and pass the contents of the DVD to a computer (assuming the DVD isn't copy-protected, which would make things slightly more complicated) and rip/burn another DVD, this time without the offensive tracks.

As I don't do this often, I can't suggest you good utilities, but this is possible to do.